# C++ Linking one library through the other

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, shared-libraries

libA.so links to libB.so

main links to libB.so but it can't access symbols of libA.so. Why? Is there a way i can make symbols of libA.so visible to main through libB.so

```
cat a.cc 
#include<iostream>
void hello() {
   return;
}

cat  b.cc
#include <iostream>
void goodbye() {
  return;
}


cat c.cc m
#include<iostream>
void goodbye();
void hello();
void tc() {
  goodbye();
  hello();
}


cat main.cc
#include<iostream>
void hello();
void goodbye();
int main() {
   hello();
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working, how can i make it work?

```
g++ -fPIC -c a.cc b.cc 
g++ a.o b.o -shared -o libA.so


g++ -fPIC -c c.cc
g++ c.o -shared -lA -L. -o libB.so 

g++ main.cc -lA -L.
g++ main.cc -lB -L.
/tmp/cci2foLo.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Z5hellov'
./libA.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

ldd libB.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa733d000)
libA.so => ./libA.so (0x00002b0f9a92a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b0f9ab5e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b0f9ae64000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b0f9b0e8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b0f9b2ff000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b0f9a504000)
```

How can i link main to A through B?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic libraries are very similar to normal executable programs, and are separate and distinct entities that are loaded separately.

And they only export their *own* symbols, not the ones of libraries it links to.

That means `main.cc` can use the functions, classes, and symbols in general from the libraries that it explicitly link to. If you want to use symbols from the library `A` you need to link with the library `A`.